# Unable to generate CSV from AVRO file in java

Tags: java, spring, csv, avro, converters

Unable to generate AVRO to CSV, not able to figure out the error root cause

### pom.xml-

```
<jackson.version>2.12.4</jackson.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

### Model-

```
package com.test.employee.model;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "modifiedTimestamp", "score"})

public class EmployeeModel {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("modifiedTimestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime modifiedTimestamp;
    
    @JsonProperty("score")
    private String score;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private String employeeId;
 
    public EmployeeModel(String id, String name, ZonedDateTime modifiedTimestamp,
    @JsonProperty("score"), String score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.modifiedTimestamp = modifiedTimestamp;
        this.score = score;
    } 

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public ZonedDateTime getModifiedTimestamp() {
        return modifiedTimestamp;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test {
        private File avroToCsv(File avroFile, String path) {
                File result = new File(path);

                if (result.exists()) result.delete();

                try {
                    GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record> datum = new GenericDatumReader<>();
                    DataFileReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new DataFileReader<>(avroFile, datum);
                    GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(reader.getSchema()); 
                    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
                    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(EmployeeModel.class).withHeader();
                    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(result , true);
                    CsvGenerator csvGenerator = csvMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(outStream);
                    ObjectWriter csvWriter = csvMapper.writer(schema);

                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        reader.next(record);
                        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(modifDate);
                        ZonedDateTime modifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
                        EmployeeModel tempModel = new EmployeeModel(
                                record.get("id").toString(),
                                record.get("name").toString(),
                                modifiedDate,
                                record.get("score").toString()
                        );
                    csvWriter.writeValue(csvGenerator, tempModel);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    
        public static void main(String []args) {
            avroToCsv(new File("abc.avro"), "c:/test/ModifiedUsers.csv");
        }   
}
```

---

Schema object contains headers as: "id", "name", "modifiedTimestamp", "score"
Employee model contains values as: "123456", "demoapp", 2021-04-16T19:00:54 , "2.4"

---

Exception received:
//

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [no message for java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._wrapAsIOE(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:509)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:933)
    at com.test.employee.Test.avroToCsv(AvroToCsv.java:164)
    at com.test.employee.Test.main(Test.java:41)
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.setCurrentValue(GeneratorBase.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeStartObject(GeneratorBase.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    ... 7 more
```

---

//
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an object, expecting field name
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:1961)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator._verifyValueWrite(CsvGenerator.java:957)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvGenerator.writeStartObject(CsvGenerator.java:584)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeStartObject(GeneratorBase.java:286)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:151)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)

---

```
Issue Identified with library:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/114
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not schema, or lack thereof (kind of), but rather that you are constructing new `ObjectWriter` instance for every value: this will not work.

Instead, you need to construct a `SequenceWriter` if you want to write a sequence of rows separately. Something like:

```
ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writerFor(schema);
SequenceWriter sw = ow.writeValues(outStream);
```

and then use

```
sw.write(tempModel);
```